# How many more females in different sized populations

Tags: proportion, ratio, population-attributable-fraction

|  | Delhi | Mumbai |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Males | 75 | 60 |
| Females | 125 | 40 |
| TOTAL | 200 | 100 |

In two cities of Delhi and Mumbai we have different population. I need to know how many females are more in Delhi given that we need to preserve the ratio of Mumbai (males: females) in Delhi.

Comment: Do you want to compare two proportions between two cities?

Comment: yes. I need to know that how many more females we have in Delhi, if we had the same proportion of males : females as in mumbai

Answer (score 0):

Mumbai has a ratio of 3:2 males to females. If Delhi had the same ratio as Mumbai it would need 50 females. 75/3*2=50. But Delhi has extra females. 125-50=75.

Delhi has 75 extra females.

Comment: But what about the difference in population size? How does that factor in?

Comment: Ok, think of it this way. Delhi has more males than Mumbai. How much more? 75/60=1.25. What is 1.25 times bigger than 40? 40*1.25=50. If Delhi had the same ratio of 3:2 it needs to have 50 females. But it has 125 females. To get from 125 to 50 is 125-50=75. There is other information you can gather using this table. e.g. how much bigger/smaller is the ratio of of males:females in Delhi vs Mumbai=>(75/125)/(60/40)=0.4. Or we can find the odds of being female in Mumbai vs Delhi (another different ratio). But you keep saying "need to preseve the ratio/if we had the same propotion as in Mumbai"

Comment: So the ratio of male to female in delhi is different than mumbai. It may be more or less. We want to know how much more or less than mumbai. and what does that mean in absolute terms for woman in delhi [assuming male population in delhi is correct.]

Comment: ok, what is the ratio of M:F in Mumbai? 3/2. What is the ratio of M:F in Delhi? 3/5. How much bigger or smaller is the ratio of Delhi to Mumbai? (3/5)/(3/2)=0.4. What is 40% of 125? 50. 50 is how many females Delhi would have if it had the same ratio of M:F as Mumbai. 75/50 is the same as 60/40. So how many extra women does Delhi have? 125-50=75. I have now given you three explanations of how to get the answer. If this still does not make sense, you need to go and revise ratios and division. I'm sorry, I can't squeeze anymore explanation into the comment space.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I get this part I was trying to add something else to the question too. But my bad I am doing a job at it. Thanks for this.